# How to avoid flickering after templated WPF window restore? No answers found

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-interface, templates

I use templated WPF window.
My custom style works fine except the 1 thing... And I found that all examples from internet has this issue.
When I minimize window it works fine - window minimizes quickly. When I restore window it works so bad - title area with icon logo and minimize-restore-close buttons makes a fat footprint which are shown for 1-1.5 seconds.

The behavior of my custom window has differences from other windows. Process of minimize-restore of standard OS windows are smooth and has some animations (win 8). But my custom window does this quickly without any standard effects...

So, what I should to do to make my custom window restoring with standard effects?